# How to include hash tag in drupal_goto path?

Tags: php, drupal-7

Is there any way to include # tag in drupal_goto?

```html
function a_first_init() {
  global $base_url;
  $node_id=arg(1);
  $url='/events#/$node_id';
  $path=$base_url.$url;
    if(!user_is_logged_in) {
      drupal_goto($path);
    }
 
}
```

I have tried above code,but it's not working.any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is drupal help url (docs) -  [**Click Here**](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7). How to use **drupal_goto** function.

Syntax:-

```
<?php drupal_goto($path = '', array $options = array(), $http_response_code = 302) ?>
```

Code:-

```
<?php 
   function a_first_init() {
   $node_id=arg(1);
   if(!user_is_logged_in) {
      drupal_goto("events", array('fragment' => $node_id));
     }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For drupal 7 use 'fragment' options key. see docs

```
drupal_goto('url', array('fragment' => $node->nid));
```

Comment: **drupal_goto** -
 [link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7.x) uses **url** -
 [link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7.x)